# "You need to undergo the medical tests within 6 months from the departure date"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I want to make a statement that means you need to undergo the medical tests *not before* 6 months from the date of departure.

In other words, the medical tests should not be taken earlier than 6 months or trying again "within 6 months period prior to the departure date".

I am confused as to which one is correct:

> 1. You need to undergo the medical tests *within* 6 months from the departure date.
> 2. You need to undergo the medical tests *not before* 6 months from the departure date.
> 3. You need to undergo the medical tests *within 6 months period prior* to the departure date.

Please help with the correct wording. Emphasis used only to illustrate the troublesome part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest choice would be:

> 1. You need to undergo the medical tests ***within 6 months period prior*** to the departure date.

However, to be clear and easy to understand, you would better rewrite it as:

> You need to undergo the medical tests ***within the period of six months prior*** to the departure date.

(Numbers less than thirteen are usually spelt out).

Answer (score 14):

I have two suggestions, of which I like the first better.

> You need to get the medical tests **during** the six months before your departure date.
>
> You need to get the medical tests **no earlier than** six months before your departure date.

The preposition *within* is usually used for time periods after the reference time, so *within six months of the departure date* would normally be understood to mean the six months after the departure date. Using it for the earlier time period is confusing.

Comment: +1 but I like your second suggestion better!

Comment: I too like the second one better!

Answer (score 4):

You could always just spell it out and be super-clear:

> You need to undergo the medical tests prior to the departure date, but no more than six months before.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a rewrite like this:

A medical test must be taken **inside the six month time window** before your departure date.

Answer (score 0):

"you need to do this within 6 months of the departure date" can also mean within the 6 months before the departure. If you fear there will be some confusion whether you mean before or after the departure, say "within the 6 months prior to departure"